# "shebang /usr/bin/env python" invoking the wrong Python interpreter

Tags: python, bash, shebang

What's happening, here?!

```
$ /usr/bin/env which python
/home/dbanas/.local/bin/python

$ /home/dbanas/.local/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.3 -- EPD_free 7.3-2 (64-bit)

$ /usr/bin/env python -V
Python 2.4.3
```

I stumbled upon this, trying to debug one of my Python scripts, which uses a

`#! /usr/bin/env python`

first line. And I don't understand how it's possible.

Thanks!
-db

I did just notice that '~/.local/bin/python' is a link, not an executable. Would that break the '/usr/bin/env ...' flow somehow?

Perhaps, this is a more succinct way to express the fundamental puzzle?:

```
$ env python -V
Python 2.4.3

$ python -V
Python 2.7.3 -- EPD_free 7.3-2 (64-bit)
```

It just keeps getting curioser and curioser:

```
$ which python
/home/dbanas/.local/bin/python

$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.executable'
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Do you have an extra space in the shebang ?

Comment: the problem doesn't really have to do with shebang but with env running a different version than what `which` says it should. You might want to clarify the quesiton. What shell are you using? what does `env` (alone) report for your path?

Comment: @klashxx, I have a space in between '#!' and '/usr/bin/env'. Is that what you meant? Removing that space doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Comment: @george, Yes, I agree, the puzzler for me is: "How can '/usr/bin/env which python' yield a different python than the one that '/usr/bin/env python' invokes?" I'm using bash. '"/usr/bin/env | grep '^PATH'" yields: PATH=/apps/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc:/apps/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin:~/bin:~/.local/bin:... And I have confirmed that a 'python' can NOT be found in any of the directories preceeding '~/.local/bin'.

Comment: What do you get if you add `import sys` and `print sys.path` in your script?

Comment: Also, remove that space, even if it doesn't look like it's doing anything.

Comment: try `where python` with and without `env`

Comment: @tristan, Unfortunately, my script doesn't run under 2.4, because it uses the 'with open(...' idiom. So, I get a syntax error upon interpretation, under 2.4. At any rate, what you're suggesting would give me a clue about where python modules would be searched for, but I'm strugglling to understand how the python executable itself is being searched for.

Comment: @ george, I'm assuming you meant, "which python":

  `$ env which python
  /home/dbanas/.local/bin/python

  $ which python
  /home/dbanas/.local/bin/python
`

As you can see, the 'env' makes no difference, which is as expected.

Comment: @dbanas, yes, I was hoping that possibly the module paths would clue you into where the interpreter lives. Is the virtualenv active? `print sys.executable` will tell you which interpreter is loading.

Comment: Is it a hard link or a soft link?

Comment: no I meant `where` to see all of the versions on the path  - might give a clue.

Comment: Oh.  In your shell, do a `env | grep -i python` do you have anything that would put to 2.4.3? (@dbanas)

Comment: oops sorry `where` is a `csh` special. I dont know if `bash` has an equivalent.

Comment: @tristan, Here's what I get: $ env | grep -i python
PYTHONHOME=/home/dbanas/.local
PYTHONPATH=/home/dbanas/hotel/work/src:

Comment: try `type -a python` under `bash`.  Also in case you just installed (or moved) the python executable be sure to run a new shell so it sees it on startup.

Comment: Let's see the value of `$PATH`. Also, what directory are you in when you run the command? How about the script? What directory is it run from? `env` will return the first instance of the program found in `$PATH`. The current directory is relevant because that may be short circuiting the search.

Comment: @george, Here's what I get:  
  
    `$ type -a python
    python is /home/dbanas/.local/bin/python
    python is /usr/bin/python`

Comment: @george, I think I've already answered your question, re: $PATH, above.

Comment: @dbanas what does 'python -E -V' vs. 'env python -E -V' look like? Is your symlink pointing to a script instead of an actual interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely what's happening is you don't have your `PATH` variable exported to the environment. In that case, `/usr/bin/env` won't have a `PATH` set, and its [`execvp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) call will end up searching a small set of default directories (which typically includes `/usr/bin`, naturally).

To see this (in `bash`):

```
$ export PATH
$ declare -p PATH  # verify PATH is exported, denoted by the -x
declare -x PATH="<my usual path, omitted...>"
$ /usr/bin/env python -V  # shows my own python build
Python 2.7.6
$ export -n PATH  # un-export PATH
$ declare -p PATH
declare -- PATH="<my usual path, omitted...>"
$ /usr/bin/env python -V  # shows the system (/usr/bin/python) version
Python 2.6.6
```

So, in summary, make sure to `export PATH` somewhere in your shell dotfiles.

Answer (score 0):

`python` seems to be an `alias` in your shell. Unalias it

```
unalias python
```

and try again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Linger, pardon? This looks like an answer to me (though I don't think it's correct -- an alias would show up in the output of `type`).